# Is this bad practice: getMyObject().method()

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a function which returns an object :

```
getMyObject(){
   //do stuff here
   return object;
}
```

Is it bad practice to call a method (that doesn't return anything) on the function name itself:

```
getMyObject().method();
```

instead of assigning a variable to the return object and then calling the method on that variable :

```
var returnedObject = getMyObject();
returnedObject.method();
```

I am working with an html page that has many nested frames, and I have access to a function that returns one of these frames. The frame might be used several times within other functions in my script, and I was wondering if it would be ok for me to access the frame in the way asked above, or if it would be better to declare a global variable.

**EDIT: ** Ahh I haven't gotten a chance to use jQuery.  Good to know!

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with that. It's like jQuery with chaining functions, e.g. `.add(object).hide().show()`.

Comment: As a general rule, I'd say it's not bad practice if you know why you're doing it and you can justify your reasoning. That being said, you probably want to avoid introducing complexity where it is not needed. If you choose to go with a global var, I propose you create one global object where you store all your 'shared' vars. When I use jQuery, I usually tack a namespace onto jQuery itself and store shared vars in that object. ex: jQuery.myApp = {}. The trade-off being slower variable access vs global pollution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, method chaining is ***the better practice*** IMHO. If a function returns an object, upon which you want to call a method, but you do not need to reference that object after calling that method, don't assign it to a variable.

Also, jQuery code does this *all the time*(1):

```
$('#foo').on('click',function(){});
    /\      \\
    ||       \\  
    ||        \\
function call returns jQ object <============|
                  \\                        ||
                   \\call method "on" upon _||
```

(1)To clarify: I do not claim that all jQ methods return an object `.attr()` or `.prop()` don't. What I mean by *"all the time"* is actually that the scenario the OP describes is *very* common in jQ code (function call, invoke method on returned object):

```
var someString = $($('.foo').get(0)).attr('id');//tricky little bugger, this :)
var aBool = $('#foo').prop('checked');
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't do this *all the time*. They do it for **setters** and some other places. Maybe that's obvious to us, but not to everyone. For example, when you use something like `.prop("checked")`, it returns a boolean, not the selected elements.

Comment: @Ian: you don't just call `$.prop('checked')`, you call it on a jQ object, which is often created by passing a string (query selector) or DOM reference (`this` mostly) to the main jQ function: `$('#foo')` is a function call, returns jQ object, so `$('#foo').prop('checked')` is exactly the same as what the op does: `getMyObject().method()`

Comment: I never said you call it like `$.prop("checked")` - my point is that not **all** jQuery methods return the jQuery object, so you shouldn't claim it. For example, `$("#element_id").attr("data-id", 1).show()` is fine, and can continue caching, when you add something like `.prop("checked")` to the end, it doesn't continue chaining of the jQuery object.

Comment: Otherwise, I think your statement "If a function returns an object, upon which you want to call a method, but you do not need to reference that object after calling that method, don't assign it to a variable." is spot on and is the important thing to consider.

Comment: @Ian: I'm not saying _all jQ methods return an object_, I'm saying that, when using jQ, you're constantly calling functions that return objects, and invoking methods upon that returned object. By no means do I mean that all jQ methods return an object... heaven forbid

Comment: **I** know what you meant. But it confused me when you said "all the time". Which I guess I took as "every time". That's all I'm trying to say :)

Comment: @Ian: edited my answer to avoid ambiguity. Just read my first reply-comment... sorry if I came across as a defensive jerk or know-it-all

Comment: Seriously no problem! Again, **I** know what you meant. I was just trying to make sure you understood where I was coming from and show you possible confusion. Thanks for updating, I think it's a great description :)

Comment: @Ian: Again there was some confusion, in my last comment, when I said _"Just read my first reply-comment"_, I actually meant to say: _"I've just read my first reply-comment and noticed I might have come across as defensive know-it-all jerk"_. I didn't mean to say _"Just read my first reply-comment again"_. You were absolutely right to point out that my original answer could be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is perfectly OK. jQuery for example uses this as well. It returns objects on which you can call methods immediatley. This is called chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, no. Chaining method calls like that is usually simpler, more elegant, and easier to read. However, there are a few cases when it's better to use a variable.

1. If you use a method (or chain of methods) a lot of times, you can use a variable if it makes the code cleaner.
2. If the method takes a long time to process, it's better to cache the result. For example, if you have some method called `calculateResults()`, and it pulls data from a database, that takes some time. If the data doesn't change, you'll be incurring that cost for each call to the method. Better to store it in a variable and reuse it.
3. If the method has side effects, you should be careful about calling it more than once. Those side-effects will be inflicted each time you call it. Again, as an example, if you have a function like `nextItem()` that advances to the next item and returns it (a la Java iterators), then calling it more than intended will actually change the result. In this case, you have no choice but store the result, since calling it more than once will produce incorrect behavior.

Otherwise, chain away!

Comment: Can you explain points 2 and 3 a bit more in detail? I don't agree to point 1 btw, since if you make your method-names meaningfull, it helps reading the code easier (as you already said).

Comment: @Zim84 Done, hopefully that's better.

Comment: @JakeKing Point number 2 isn't valid IMO. There is nothing to stop someone from caching within the chain method and checking that cache rather than performing some expensive operation.

Comment: @FeistyMango That's true, but there's an equal chance that it's not caching. Sure, if you know that it will be cached, it doesn't matter, but if you don't... Also, there are plenty of operations that you can know for a fact don't get automatically cached. It could even be something you wrote yourself. In that case, the point is still very relevant.